# Share an angular Component INSTANCE across the application

Tags: angular, angular9

I have an angular application that contains a Board where user activity is displayed. This Board is only visible in some of the areas in the application. Data on the board should not persist in DB. When I'm navigating through the application, I've observed that a new Instance of the board is being created every time, hence all the data that the previous board contains is lost.

I've tried copying all the data to a Singleton service and pulling it back, but it seems tedious

So I tried to create a *shared component instance* and add it at the required views, but it didn't work

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit...{
       
    service ;//Singleton service

    constructor(private injector: Injector,private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver){
        const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(BoardComponent);
        const componentRef = factory.create(this.injector);
        this.service.setComponentRef(componentRef);
    }
    ......
}
```

At a particular view, I've tried inserting the component instance

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: `<ng-template #vwRef></ng-template><br/> <p>User Log</p>.......`,
  selector: "supervisor-panel",
  styleUrls: ["./supervisor-panel.component.css"],
}) 
export class SupervisorViewComponent implements OnInit...{

    @ViewChild("vwRef",{read: ViewContainerRef})
    refTemplate: ViewContainerRef;

    constructor(private service : SingletoneService){  }

    ngOnInit(){
       let componentRef = serivce.getComponentRef();
       this.refTemplate.insert(componentRef.hostView); 
    }

}
```

this results in an error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '_lView' of undefined
> at ViewContainerRef.insert (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:33661:81)

**Is this the correct approach or is there an alternate solution ?**

Comment: I don't think it's possible to have a true singleton component. You could create your component in your root component/app component, which should only initialize it once. I think you were on the right path when you started on a singleton service and then inject into your components.

Comment: Your concept to introduce a service which holds the state of said component is absolutly feasible and the de facto way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

For that case you can use the localStorage, it is available globally and the data will persist.

Comment: he wont be able to listen to the changes of a localstorage item

Comment: It is possible with an `Observable`

Comment: mentamarindo, Motassem MK : Appreciate your ideas. But isn't it conceptually same as writing/fetching data from a singleton service

Answer (score 0):

This approach is wrong, you should use a state management library for such things, or if your application is small or you don't have a lot of shared data between components, you can just create an Observable on singleton service.

basically you'll create a global observable variable, listen to its changes in that component to do the actions you need to do when it's changed, then you can call "next" on that observable with the new value from any component you want

take a look:
https://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-build-angular2-apps-using-rxjs-observable-data-services-pitfalls-to-avoid/